# Why can't external communication with kubernetes Pod's container

Tags: http, cross-origin-read-blocking

1.When first deploying a pod, to communicate between internal containers
set hostname

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: testml
  labels:
    app: testml-pod
spec:
  hostname: testmlhostname
  subdomain: testml-subdomain
  containers:
  - name: testmlserver
    image: test_ml_server:3.7
    ports:
      - containerPort: 5100
      - containerPort: 8080
    env:
      - name: POD_NAME
        valueFrom:
          fieldRef:
            fieldPath: metadata.name
    volumeMounts:
      - name: testmlserver-api
        mountPath: /app/testml/api
      - name: testmlserver-csv
        mountPath: /app/testml/csv

  - name: testmldb
    image: test_ml_db:1.4
    ports:
      - containerPort: 1433
    env:
      - name: POD_NAME
        valueFrom:
          fieldRef:
            fieldPath: metadata.name
    volumeMounts:
      - name: testmldb
        mountPath: /var/opt/mssql/data

  volumes:
  - name: testmlserver-api
    hostPath:
      path: /usr/testmlhostpath/testmlserver/api
  - name: testmlserver-csv
    hostPath:
      path: /usr/testmlhostpath/testmlserver/csv
  - name: testmldb
    hostPath:
      path: /usr/testmlhostpath/testmldb
```

2.Deploy nodeport service to access the web outside

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: testml-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: testml-web
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    nodePort: 30080
  - name: testml-python
    port: 5100
    targetPort: 5100
    protocol: TCP
    nodePort: 30051

  - name: testml-db
    port: 1433
    targetPort: 1433
    protocol: TCP
    nodePort: 30014
  selector:
    app: testml-pod
```

3. Running a python server in the server container
   'http://testmlhostname:5100'

After setting like this
By connecting to the web from outside through nodeport
Call the python server with'http:testmlhostname:5100'.

[image]

The calling url of the python server is executed using'http://HOSTNAME(testmlhostname):5100'.
The web is accessed from outside through nodeport.
Why does CORB happen?

When I call the python server with curl from inside the container it reacts, but when I call it from the web I get a CORB error.

Answer (score -1):

This issue is not related to k8s. Its CORS exception, you need to use "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowOrigin

Comment: Yes, so the python server handled response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] ='*'
spring app & I applied jquery.ajax-cross-origin.min.js and set it to Ajax crossOrigin:true.